# matrix norm and its eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to bound |A| by its largest eigenvalue (or its largest eigenvalue scaled by a constant), where A is a real square matrix and |.| is the Frobenius norm?

The difficulty I had is when A is not symmetric, there's no obvious relation between the matrix norm and its eigenvalues. A related fact is ||A||<=|A|, where ||.|| is the spectral norm of A (the square root of the largest eigenvalue of A'A). Another fact is that |A|<=sqrt(n)*||A||, where n is the dimension of A. But they're not helpful here. My feeling is when A is not symmetric, its eigenvalues are hard to relate to.

Comment: hint: Suppose $A$ is a non-zero nilpotent matrix and....

Comment: user8675309, great example